# Why isn't my javascript countdown working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, countdown, tigra-calendar

I'm having a problem with a countdown i'm making for a webapp in javascript. The page has an input that's a calendar, that will provide the date to the countdown and it has the countdown itself!

My problem is that i can't put the date provided by the calendar to work in the countdown.

The time in the countdown has to be provided in seconds so, here's my code:

The calendar input:

```
<form style="margin-top:10px;"><input id="date" class="tcal"></form>
```

the script to convert the date in seconds:

```
var target_date = document.getElementById('date').value;
var target_date_secs = target_date.getTime();
var target_date_in_secs = target_date_secs / 1000;
var today = new Date();
var today_secs = today.getTime();
var today_in_secs = today_secs / 1000;
var final_time_secs = target_date_in_secs - today_in_secs;
document.write(final_time_secs);
```

and the problem is that this doesn't print anything, when it should print the time left in seconds...

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: And what do you see in the [`console`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript) when you execute this?

Comment: nothing, only the calendar appears!

Comment: So you don't see something like `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'getTime'`?

Comment: No, I don't see thar error...

Comment: And you are looking in the `console`, right? You know what the `console` is?

Comment: Yes, i know, and no, no errors!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/pVy6L/ Well, I see it in Chromium, Chrome, FireFox and Opera. Don't know what you have for a browser or where you are looking..

Comment: ok now it gave me this error
Uncaught ReferenceError: finaldate is not defined
but that's because it's isn't defined...

Comment: I see it in Chrome...

Comment: So this line `var target_date = document.getElementById('date').value;` grabs the `string` from the `input` and assigns it to `target_date`. The string object doesn't have a method `getTime`, (you call `target_date.getTime();`), that is a method of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. So you need to convert the `string` representation of a date into a real `Date` object.

Comment: how can I do that? is there any function to do it?

Comment: Did you read the `Date` documentation that I linked to?

Comment: In my comment, the first mention of `Date` that is a link.

Comment: And then, I would take the `string` provided by your calendar (no idea what the format is as you haven't given an example), and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it into parts and then use the following form of the constructor `new Date(year, month [, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);`

Comment: Insert `console.log(target_date);` after this line `var target_date = document.getElementById('date').value;` and update your question with the `string` that is displayed in the `console`.

Comment: I really didnt realize yet what am i supposed to do...

Comment: Until you give us the format of the `string` that is returned by your calendar, then it is impossible to give you any further and good advice. (ie, is it "dd/mm/yyy" or perhaps "mm/dd/yyy" or "yyyy-mm-dd" or one of other many possibilities)

Comment: oh, sorry, when I put document.write(target_date); it prints :
Friday, March 28th 2014

Comment: If that is the format that your calendar uses then you have potentially a fair amount of work to do, as you will need to decode the day (name) and the month (name) into a number, by using a [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to look it up. Is that the only format that your calendar has options for? What are you using?

Comment: i'm using this [calendar](http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/)

Comment: http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar_pro/docs/#onclick_function_example  I would suggest using the 3rd argument: milliseconds, that way you can feed that number directly to the `Date` constructor by using `new Date(value);`

Comment: I added that calendar as a tag to your question, you can now easily look to see what others have been having problems with (and get a feeling for it's popularity). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tigra-calendar

Comment: I was thinking about getting a new calendar, that was easier to use.. Any ideia of what can be usefull for me?

Comment: I have no experience with calendars, try looking at what is popular here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calendar+javascript

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create a Date-Obj

```
...
    var date = new Date(target_date);
    var target_date_secs = date.getTime();
...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: well, I made this changes and it printed "NaNNaN" (without quotation marks) when I wrote document.write(target_date_secs);

Comment: what do you mean with this?

Comment: this fiddle should print the number of seconds below the input field - isnt that what you wanted to achieve?